# \cref not referencing \chapter which is in separate file

Tags: pdftex, cross-referencing, cleveref

I started using `\cref` from the `cleveref` package because it gives me better readability than `\autoref` from `hyperref` package. But I am having problems with `\cref` command not recognizing the label that has been put into the external `\chapter` or `\section` etc. environment. As I wrote my thesis long time ago, and was fiddling with the look of it in last few days, problem occurred when I try to reference outside chapters with `\cref`, error that it gives is `cref` reference format for label type `' undefined`, keep in mind that pictures are being referenced correctly, being in the same chapter or external.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{report}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\usepackage{cleveref}  

\begin{document}
%------------------------------------------------------
\include{MainMatter/Chapter1}  
\include{MainMatter/Chapter2}  
\include{MainMatter/Chapter3}  
\include{MainMatter/Chapter4}  
\include{MainMatter/Chapter5}  
\include{MainMatter/Chapter6}  
\include{MainMatter/Chapter7}  
%======================================================  
\end{document}
```

So next I have a `chapter4.tex` in one of the sections that I am referencing some other chapter or section:

```
For this purpose special gripper fingers have been constructed and implemented (more in `\cref{Ch:GripHandBeerBottGlass}`).
```

Which is called from a separate file in `chapter6.tex` and labeled

```
\chapter{Gripper for Handling Beer Bottles and Beer Glasses}\label{Ch:GripHandBeerBottGlass}
```

I know that it works with `hyperref` package, but not with `cleveref` package. With `\cref` I just get

```
For this purpose special gripper fingers have been constructed and implemented (more in ??).
```

As mentioned by Christian to upload basic parts of the Chapters.

```
%This is the Chpater 4 Chapter4.tex
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize \slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
\chapter{Modelling of System Layout}\label{Ch:ModelSysLay}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
%============================================================================
        \subsubsection{Gripper and Gripper Fingers}\label{Sss:C4_GripnGriFing}

 \newcommand{\parl}{\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}}
 For manipulating of bottles, glasses, fixtures and opening of bottles in the workcell there should be a robot gripper that can utilize gripper jaw to its full potential. As it was mentioned in the beginning, these gripper jaws should be able to pick up bottle from a crate, take a bottle for opening and in the end pouring, and manipulating fixtures if needed. For this purpose special gripper fingers have been constructed and implemented (more in \cref{Ch:GripHandBeerBottGlass}).\parl%
```

As it is seen, I'm trying to reference Chapter 6 in the subsubsection of the Chapter 4.

```
%This is the Chpater 6 Chapter6.tex
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize \slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}

%============================================================================
\chapter{Gripper for Handling Beer Bottles and Beer Glasses}\label{Ch:GripHandBeerBottGlass}
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant files -- `\include{...}` is most times not really helpful in tracking errors

Comment: Should I upload preamble and any two chapters that problem is occurring, or? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The preamble is already in your post above  -- try to reduce your document to that one that still shows the wrong feature (i.e. make a copy and throw all stuff out that does not belong to this question ;-))

Comment: Well, we've to glue your fragments in a working file still

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code in one contiguous document here, instead of multiple fragments?

Comment: Are you by any chance using `classicthesis`? I'm encountering a very similar problem with referencing chapters - it occurs specifically when I `\usepackage{classicthesis}`, and it doesn't seem to matter whether or not the chapter is defined in a separate file.

Comment: @ali_m Sorry for a late answer, job is taking all my time up, so I am not that active right now. No, I did not use clasicthesis. First I tried to use it with my own class, but then just used the standard report. I think that the problem was with my Babel settings, as I was using Serbian Cyrillic and English language. When I split the document into Serbian part and English part, everything went away.